# how to access the outer class members in subclass wherin inner class is inherited

Tags: java, inner-classes

//below class is the example where in subclass extends the innerclass and from the subclass i am trying to access the methods of outer class i.e encapsulating class of inner class.

```
package innerClass;

public class outterclass {
    private int outer=24;
    protected int get_outer(){
        return outer;
    }
    protected static class innerclass{
        private int outer=25;
        protected int get_outer(){
            return outer;
        }
    }
}
package innerClass;

public class subclass_B extends outterclass.innerclass {

    void parent_class_info_fetch(){
        System.out.println(get_outer());
        //i want to access the outer class get_outer method and how do i achieve that?
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InheritanceStaticInnerClass_B isb=new InheritanceStaticInnerClass_B();
        isb.parent_class_info_fetch();      
    }
}
```

Comment: Marko Topolnik answer is correct. But it is something very broken if you need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `innerclass` is not an inner class. It is a static nested class and bears no special relationship to its enclosing class. You cannot reach an instance of the enclosing class because no such instance is available to `innerclass` or its subclasses.

If `innerclass` was indeed inner, then you would have to instantiate it with an enclosing instance:

```
outterclass outer = new outerclass();
subclass_B b = outer.new subclass_B();
```

Then, in `parent_class_info_fetch()` you could write

```
outterclass.this.get_outer()
```

to reach that method.

Of course, there would be several layers of bad practices in such code, so consider this just an academic execrise.

You should also learn about the basic naming conventions in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,so,i have got no solution for the above code until i make it as a inner class.

Answer (score 0):

The class `outterclass.innerclass` is a *static* class field, which means you don't necessarily have an enclosing instance of `outterclass`. On the other hand, the method `get_outer` of `outterclass` is an instance method, so you'll need the enclosing instance to call it.

With the class hierarchy you have, you'd have to make `get_outer` static (which requires making `outer` static as well).

Comment: Thanks manouti,will do the same and it works.is it the best practice?

Comment: @Prash As mentioned in the other answer by Marko, you would have to make `innerclass` really inner to begin with. Otherwise, with what you have as static class field, the simplest solution is to make the method static.